# Server - Client communication causing Shapes to not Render on Canvas Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, socket.io, game-development

I'm trying to create an online multiplayer game, but for some reason I can't get the players to be drawn on the screen. I think the problem is related to the server not correctly sending the data to the client, but I've included the whole (commented) code just in case that's not the case.

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

    <title>Online Game</title>

    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  </head>

  <body>
      <canvas id="myCanvas" width="600" height="600"></canvas
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.9.0/addons/p5.sound.min.js"></script>

    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Pretty straightforward, I define the canvas and the client-side script, `script.js`

`index.js`:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require("http").createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(http);

app.get('/',function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

app.use('/',express.static(__dirname));

/* Server */
// Movement keys
const W = 87;
const A = 65;
const S = 83;
const D = 68;

// The data
let data = {players:{}} ;

let width = 600;
let height = 600;

io.on("connection", socket => {
  // New player connected
  console.log("player connected");

  // Create new player
  data.players[socket.id] = {
    pos:{x:300, y:300},
    speed:10,
    size:30,
    color:{r:255, g:0, b:0}
  };

console.log(data);

  socket.on("disconnect", () => {
    // Player  disconnected
    console.log("player disconnected");
    // Delete player
    delete data.players[socket.id];
  });

  // Movement event
  socket.on("move", key => {
    // Get the current player
    let player = data.players[socket.id];
    console.log(player.pos)
    // Check which movement key was pressed, and move accordingly
    if(key == W) {
        player.pos.y -= player.speed;
        console.log('up')
    }
    if(key == A) {
        player.pos.x -= player.speed;
        console.log('left')
    }
    if(key == S) {
        player.pos.y += player.speed;
        console.log('down')
    }
    if(key == D) {
        player.pos.x += player.speed;
        console.log('right')
    }

    // Check if player is touching the boundry, if so stop them from moving past it
    if(player.pos.x > width - player.size) {
        player.pos.x = width - player.size;
    }
    if(player.pos.x < 0) {
        player.pos.x = 0;
    }
    if(player.pos.y > height - player.size) {
        player.pos.y = height - player.size;
    }
    if(player.pos.y < 0) {
        player.pos.y = 0;
    }
  });
  
});


http.listen(4141);
```

This is the server code, and it handles creating the players and tracking movement. A bit sloppily written

`script.js`:

```
const socket = io();

/* Setup */
let canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

/* Update & Events */
// Create the movement keys
const W = 87;
const A = 65;
const S = 83;
const D = 68;

// Get the update from the server
socket.on("update", data => {});

//receive input to move player
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
  if (event.key === 'w') {
    socket.emit("move", W);
  }
  if (event.key === 'a') {
    socket.emit("move", A);
  }
    if (event.key === 's') {
    socket.emit("move", S);
  }
  if (event.key === 'd') {
    socket.emit("move", D);
  }
});

function draw(){
    // Draw each player
  for(let playerID of Object.keys(data.players)) {
    // Get the the player from the player's id
    let player = data.players[playerID];

    // Draw the player
      ctx.startPath();
    ctx.arc(player.pos.x, player.pos.y, player.size, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();

  }
}
draw();
```

The last `for` loop is the part that is not working. It is supposed to read the `data` map from the `update` event and render all the players at respective positions, but it is not.

I've tried debugging it. The move event has no problem, and neither does the canvas. If I hard code `ctx.fillRect(x, y, size, size)` into the program, it shows up. So I believe it has to do with the `data` variable not being sent properly. Am I missing something obvious?

**UPDATE**

So I realized I forgot to emit the update event from `index.js` and updated some of the script

`index.js`:

```
socket.on("move", key => {
    // Get the current player
    let player = data.players[socket.id];
    console.log(player.pos)
    // Check which movement key was pressed, and move accordingly
    if(key == W) {
        player.pos.y -= player.speed;
        console.log('up')
    }
    if(key == A) {
        player.pos.x -= player.speed;
        console.log('left')
    }
    if(key == S) {
        player.pos.y += player.speed;
        console.log('down')
    }
    if(key == D) {
        player.pos.x += player.speed;
        console.log('right')
    }

    // Check if player is touching the boundry, if so stop them from moving past it
    if(player.pos.x > width - player.size) {
        player.pos.x = width - player.size;
    }
    if(player.pos.x < 0) {
        player.pos.x = 0;
    }
    if(player.pos.y > height - player.size) {
        player.pos.y = height - player.size;
    }
    if(player.pos.y < 0) {
        player.pos.y = 0;
    }

      socket.emit('update', data);
  });
```

It now emits the event. But when I try to receive it,

`script.js`:

```
socket.on("update", data => {
    // Draw each player
  for(let playerID of Object.keys(data.players)) {
    // Get the the player from the player's id
    let player = data.players[playerID];

    // Draw the player
      ctx.startPath();
    ctx.arc(player.pos.x, player.pos.y, player.size, 0, Math.PI*2);
    ctx.fillStyle = "#0095DD";
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();

  }
});
```

It still doesnt render.

**UPDATE 2**

All the data now goes through, the only problem is the shapes not rendering. Something to do with canvas

Comment: The `data` variable is defined nowhere in `script.js`.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen I'm trying to get it from index.js. I forgot the emit statement, but the data comes through as undefined.

Comment: The `var data` or `let data` is missing and there is no assignment `data = ...`.

Comment: HeikoTheißen It gets it from `index.js`. With my updates, when I use `alert(data)` inside `socket.on('update', data =>{//code});` it gives `[object Object]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was something obvious. The syntax for drawing on the canvas is `beginPath` not `startPath`